# Why does my function output " the method 'forTemplate' does not exist on 'SilverStripe\View\ArrayData"

Tags: php, arrays, silverstripe

This will be my very first question on here. I hope I give you all the info you need.

I am running a personal project using silverstripe v4.8
In my template, I have a optionsetfield, which is basically just a radiofield.
The first 3 items in the options, I have hardcoded.
I wrote another function for the rest to basically get me all the names of people who can make events, loop through them, and add them as options.

When I dump my outcome, it seems to come out the way I want it:

```
array (size=1)
  'Rick' => string 'Rick' (length=4)
```

But when I try to see it in my template, it gives me:

```
Object->__call(): the method 'forTemplate' does not exist on 'SilverStripe\View\ArrayData'
```

Now when I don't add the function to my Optionset, the first 3 hardcoded items work fine.

I will post my OptionsetField and the other function below.
Thank you in advance

```
  public function createEventsFilterForm()
{
    $form = Form::create();

    $form = FieldList::create([
        OptionsetField::create('Eventfilters')
            ->setTitle('')
            ->setSource([
                'past' => 'Verlopen',
                'today' => 'Vandaag',
                'future' => 'Toekomst',
                $this->getFirstNameOfEvents()
            ])
    ]);

    return $form;
}

public function getFirstNameOfEvents()
{

    $allEvents = UpcomingEvents::get();
    foreach ($allEvents as $event) {

        $firstName = 'NVT';

        $memberProfileID = $event->MemberProfileID;

        if ($memberProfileID) {
            $firstName = [MemberProfile::get()->byID($memberProfileID)->FirstName];
        }

        $output = ArrayLib::valuekey($firstName);

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

SilverStripe templates cannot handle arrays. I guess the array got automatically converted to an `ArrayData` object.

if you want to be more explicit, you can write:

```
return new ArrayData([
  'Name' => "FOOBAR"
]);
```

and then in the template:

```
$FirstNameOfEvent <!-- this will also cause this error, because SSViwer does not know how to render ArrayData -->

<!-- but you can access object properties, like the Name that we defined: -->
$FirstNameOfEvent.Name <!-- will output FOOBAR -->
```

---

**Long explanation:**

`forTemplate` is a called by the SSViewer when rendering objects.
Basically, it's the SilverStripe equivalent to `__toString()`, whenever you are trying to output a object to the browser in a SilverStripe template, SSViewer (the renderer) will call `forTemplate` on that object.

Let me give an example:

```
class Foo extends VieableData {
  public $message = 'Hello World';
  public function forTemplate() {
    return "This is a foo object with the message '{$this->message}'";
  }
}
class PageController extends ContentController {
  public function MyFooObject() {
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

so if in your `Page.ss` template, you call `$MyFooObject` it will call the function of the same name and get an object. Because it's an object, SSViewer doesn't know how to render and will call Foo->forTemplate(). Which then will result in the output `This is a foo object with the message 'Hello World'`

`ArrayData` does not have a `forTemplate` method, thus you get the error. There are 2 ways to get around that[1]:

- subclass ArrayData and implement a `forTemplate` method that turns your data into a string (or `DBField` object) that can be output to the browser
- Don't try to render ArrayData in your Template, instead access the data directly (like in the tl;dr above, so `$MyArrayData.MyField`)[2]

[1]: the same is true for all objects
[2]: accessing object properties directly is always possible, even if you have a `forTemplate` method. `forTemplate` is just the default what to do if you don't specify a property.

---

**EDIT:**

sorry, I partially misunderstood your question/problem.
All the stuff I said above is still true, and important to understand, but it didn't answer your question.

I thought you are calling `$getFirstNameOfEvents` in the template, but actually, you are using it in a `DropDownField` (missed that part).
The thing about the SilverStripe CMS is, it also use the same templates system as the frontend for it's own things. So `DropDownField` will also use SSViewer to render. So my explanation is still true, it just happens inside `DropDownField.ss` which is a builtin template file. It does something like this:

```
<select>
<% loop $Source %>
  <option value="$Key">$Value</option>
<% end_loop %>
</select>
```

`$Source` here is your array `['past' => 'Verlopen', 'today' => 'Vandaag', 'future' => 'Toekomst', $this->getFirstNameOfEvents()]` which is automatically converted into ArrayData objects.

Now, the problem is, it doesn't work the way you think it works:

```
// the result you want:
['past' => 'Verlopen', 'today' => 'Vandaag', 'future' => 'Toekomst', 'Rick' => 'Rick']

// the result your code produces:
['past' => 'Verlopen', 'today' => 'Vandaag', 'future' => 'Toekomst', 0 => ['Rick' => 'Rick']]
```

notice how you have an array inside an array. Because `getFirstNameOfEvents` returns an array.

So what you should actually do:

```
    $source = ['past' => 'Verlopen', 'today' => 'Vandaag', 'future' => 'Toekomst'];
    $source = array_merge($source, $this->getFirstNameOfEvents());

    $form = FieldList::create([
        OptionsetField::create('Eventfilters')
            ->setTitle('')
            ->setSource($source)
    ]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reaction @Zauberfisch.
I understand your explanation. It basically gives back an arraydata wich the template doesnt how to interpret.

The only problem I have now, is that I cannot use the example given in your tl;dr part, because I render the php form in my template like this:

`<div class="filter-holder">$createEventsFilterForm</div>`

Am I missing something, or do I need to change the way I present my form?

Thanks in advance, your answer is very well explained!

Comment: I misunderstood part of my question. Updated the answer (bottom half is new)

Comment: Aaah yes. Thank you so much. I never realised I was trying to insert an array into an array and it would come out like that!